# Qustion about foreign key and how it works in spring

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities.User and orders. User can have multiple orders. I used many to one relationship. When I added a user to db the id is gerated as 1. When I am adding orders i set a user with id 2. And it worked.I don't understand why foreign key wasn't set

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String fullName;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String roles;
 
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String sum;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;



}
```

[added user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK1S3.png)

[added orders for user with invalid id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ1lr.png)

And there is no errors or something. Looks like the tables are not related
[reslts in my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT4sj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I will leave a qustion. Maybe some othere people are have the same problem. So The answer is: you need to change engine. I don't know why but spring jpa created tables with engine myIsam . It doesn't support foreign keys. You need to change it to InnoDB